# Image embedded in HTML form not getting displayed on iOS-based devices

Tags: javascript, forms, canvas, base64, drawimage

I've used the following code in an embedded code field on Google Sites to display images on my website, it's all going well on my Windows, Linux and Android devices, but they don't show up on the iPhone (whether using Chrome or Safari)!

```
<form name="submit-to-google-sheet">
   <img id="img1" width=163 height=227>
</form>

<script>
    const img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    img1.src = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=view&id={imageGoogleDriveID}";
</script>
```

some context/constraints: I'm pulling my images from my Google Drive. They are ~80kb JPEGs. I'm using a HTML form as I have other elements (buttons, fields) which I've removed from the code extract below to focus on the issue. I need to keep this form.

I've explored the Base64 format which does allow to display the images on iOS-operated devices (or so I understood). It works if I just set the image source to a Base64 URI:

```
imgBase64.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4 [...] //9k=";
```

But I can't call a Base64 file from Drive as conveniently as a JPEG.
I'm manipulating 250+ images so I can't either have the base64 strings in the middle of the code, it'd be too large to work with.

I've come up with the piece of code below, and I end up getting:

- on Android/Windows: a nice image for `img1` and a simple black square for `imgBase64`
- on iOS: an empty box for `img1` (my issue in the first place) and a simple black square for `imgBase64`

After investigation, it seems that the URI I get out of `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")` is not at all the same thing as what I get out of an encoder (such as base64.guru/converter/encode/url). It is very short and I get a lot of `A`s. It seems that the canvas is not loading the image correctly:

`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCADjAKMDAREAAhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAv/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFAEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AJ/4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP//Z`

Any idea why the conversion doesn't work?

```
<form name="myForm">
  <img id="img1" width=163 height=227>
  <img id="imgBase64" width=163 height=227>
</form>

<script>
const form = document.forms['myForm'];

var imageUrl = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=view&id={imageGoogleDriveID}";

const img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
img1.src=imageUrl;

const imgBase64 = document.getElementById('imgBase64');

const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 163;
canvas.height = 227;

img1.onload = function() {
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
}

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

imgBase64.src = dataURL; //gives me a black square

imgBase64.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4 [...] //9k="; //works fine!

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We just found the fix for iOS: when third-party cookies and cross-site tracking are blocked, the images don't load. The settings to toggle are explained [here](https://support.panopto.com/s/article/How-to-Enable-Third-Party-Cookies-in-Supported-Browsers).

Base64 wasn't the solution, since the issue was coming from pulling images from my Google Drive, i.e. a different domain from my website. However I still haven't found why `drawImage()` doesn't work.